# analytic function on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

if $g$ is an analytic function on $\{z:|z|<1\}$ and $|g(z)|=|z|$ for all $|z|<1$. Proof that $g(z)=z*exp(it)$ for some constant $t \in [0,2\pi ]$.

I know that $g(z)=r*exp(it)$ where $r=|g(z)|$ and $t=arg(g(z))$ then
$g(z)=|g(z)|*exp(it)=|z|*exp(it)$ but I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Use [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma)